# Error during drag one project to another in XCode

Tags: iphone, reference, multi-project

I have one iPhone app but I want create a second one in xCode, which will use the first apps classes.

I create the second app and drag and drop classes from first app to second one ( i have not selected "Copy items into destination group's folder" because I want the first app to work as reference )

everything seems to be ok, but when I build my second app I have errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Message", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Has anyone experienced this same issue? Is anyone aware of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

when u drag and drop the first app's data folder

You should check for "Create folder reference for any added folder" ,

Also then the color of dragged folder must change to BLUE instead of default yellow